# VF Page is getting refreshed when clicked on an Enter key in apex:inputText box

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, html, standardsetcontroller

I have an VF page which has the `apex:inputText`. When I click on Enter button, the whole VF page is getting refreshed/rerendered for no reason. I have no onkeypress events on top of the inputText box.
Below is my VF page:

```
<apex:page id="CustomHistoryTracker" standardController="Account" extensions="testcr" recordSetVar="recipients" >
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Add Recipient"  id="addRecipientsBlock">
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="6">
            <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
                 </apex:panelGrid>
                <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
                </apex:panelGrid>
                <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <!-- <input class="search" type="search" value= data-column="all" html-oninput="searchFunc(event)"> Search Contact/Investment Vehicle/Email </input> -->
                    <apex:inputText label="Search: " value="{!searchText}"  style="width:400px" >
                    </apex:inputText>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Go" action="{!searchQuery}" />
                </apex:panelGrid>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default enter key execute 'Submit' button action. You are not using submit action that is why page is getting refreshed.

Instead you can do this, to call searchquery action.

<apex:inputText label="Search: " value="{!searchText}" onkeypress="callsearchOnEnterKey(event);" style="width:400px" >
</apex:inputText>

in JS,
function callsearchOnEnterKey(event){
let x = event.which || event.keyCode;
if (x === 13) {
event.preventDefault();
//call actionFunctionName to execute searchQuery method
}
}